# Why is iphoto creating un-deletable albums?

Tags: iphone, photos.app, photos

When I sync all my photos to my mac mini iphoto then goes and creates albums on my iPhone like: **Events**, **Last 12 Months** and **Last Import** among others. I do not want these albums on my iPhone at all....

How do I get rid of them

Comment: Are these last inport photo album taking up storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to iTunes and select your device there is a tab called "Photos"

If you check and uncheck the boxes as shown:
[image]

- Check "Sync Photos"
- Chose "Selected albums, Events..." radio button
- Un-check "Last 12 Months" and "Last Import" and any you don't want
- Then check any albums you do want

You should be set.

Answer (score 0):

These 'albums' aren't real albums and can't be deleted. If you're desperate to remove them, stop syncing with iPhoto.

You can provide feedback to Apple regarding this at the following page:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html